# Iterate through list of elements and keep context of parent element in xpath selection

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a list of elements which i retrieve through find_elements_by_xpath

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'result')]")
```

Now I want to iterate through all the elements returned and find specific child elements

```
for element in results:
    field1 = element.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'field1')]")
```

My problem is that the context for the xpath selection gets ignored in the iteration so **field1** always just returns the first **element** with the **field1** class on the page regardless of the current element

Comment: Just add dot in the beggining of expression like `.//*[contains(@class, 'field1')]` to point on context

Comment: @Andersson thanks, works as intended now!

I should have probably added that the child element doesn't necessarily exist which is why when I tried this method before it failed at another point, however the debugger pointed me to a wrong place so I assumed it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andersson posted the fix is quite simple, all that was needed was the dot at the beginning of the expression:

```
for element in results:
    field1 = element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'field1')]")
```

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution worked good! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

It's easier to use css selectors (less typing) and find all the elements at once:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".result .field1")
    field1 = element
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work for my specific usecase, as i am actually checking for multiple **fields** in my results and need to keep the context for all of them, I also need to know if a element **doesn't** have **field1**